# How to access WebElement by XPath by Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to access links to result of search on this website (https://www.pibr.org.pl/pl/search/auditor?biegli=1&firmy=1&name=&post_code=&city=Warszawa) and put them in `WebElement`, but I cant locate them by class or anything. While using `xpath`:

```
MyWebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=inner-results firma]")).click();
```

I get this error:

```
"Given xpath expression "//div[@class=inner-results firma]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression."
```

How can I access all result links?

Comment: `//div[@class='inner-results firma']` is the xpath

Answer (score 4):

The `xpath` should be `"//div[@class='inner-results firma']"`, with quotation marks around the `class` attribute. You should also use `findElements` to get more than one result

```
MyWebDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='inner-results firm']")).click();
```

As a side note, variables in Java should start with lower case, `MyWebDriver` -> `myWebDriver`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the class name in single quotes, please use the below command to get the links:
`MyWebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='inner-results firma']")).click();`

Though this would click only on the first element of the class, if you want to get all the links and then click on the first link then you can use: `MyWebDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='inner-results firma']")).get(0).click();` and by using this xpath you can click on any link mentioned on the page by sending the index in the get(index) method.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly below code snippet which will give you links store in weblist:

```html
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testing {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.pibr.org.pl/pl/search/auditor?biegli=1&firmy=1&name=&post_code=&city=Warszawa");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> fromDropDwon = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/h3/a"));
        for (WebElement element : fromDropDwon) {
            System.out.println(element.getAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]