# Cannot click on checkbox using selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox

I am trying to filter out names of books in Amazon, so after I navigated successfully and after I serached for my desired book I tried to filter out all the books that are in english on the side filter panel

When I am trying in my code to click on the 'English' languge checkbox, it does click on something but the checkbox not being checked as expected, this is the html:
[image]

and this is my code:

```
        List<WebElement> list = driverWrapper.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul[aria-labelledby='p_n_feature_nine_browse-bin-title'] li"));
        for(WebElement elem: list){
            if(elem.getText().equals(LangugaeFilterOptions.ENGLISH.getValue())){
                elem.click();
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**
This is the complete element html:

```
<li id="p_n_feature_nine_browse-bin/3291437011" aria-label="English" class="a-spacing-micro" xpath="1"><span class="a-list-item">                      <a data-routing="" class="a-link-normal s-navigation-item" tabindex="-1" href="/s?k=lord+of+the+rings+the+two+towers&amp;i=stripbooks-intl-ship&amp;rh=p_n_feature_nine_browse-bin%3A3291437011&amp;dc&amp;crid=23TXZEAWG63AR&amp;qid=1595601320&amp;rnid=3291435011&amp;sprefix=lord+of+the+rings+%2Cstripbooks-intl-ship%2C314&amp;ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_nine_browse-bin_1">            <div class="a-checkbox a-checkbox-fancy s-navigation-checkbox aok-float-left"><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""><i class="a-icon a-icon-checkbox"></i><span class="a-label a-checkbox-label"></span></label></div>      <span class="a-size-base a-color-base" dir="auto">English</span>              </a>         </span></li>
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, I did removed the image from my question

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Also, the HTML image was not removed from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the click on the input tag. the click is going somewhere else. Modify the CSS/Xpath to reach the input below.
Hope that should help!

Comment: can you post me the xpath/CSS used to reach to input

Comment: Can't it is too long for the comment I will edit my question and add it I will put it under **EDIT**

Comment: findElement(By.Xpath("//ul[@aria-labelledby='p_n_feature_nine_browse-bin-title']/li/span/a/div/label/input")).click();

Comment: it's not the input value I understood what it is , it is a a href element which is a link so this is the problem and I solved it eventually.

Comment: Replace your code with the following :- List<WebElement> list = driverWrapper.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul[aria-labelledby='p_n_feature_nine_browse-bin-title'] li"));
        for(WebElement elem: list){
            if(elem.getText().equals(LangugaeFilterOptions.ENGLISH.getValue())){
                elem.FindElement(By.Xpath("//span/a/div/label/input").click();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `findElements` using `xpath` instead of `cssSelector`
Here is the link of how you can do it -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746459/11278696

Comment: I used xpath as well in order to achieve this functionality as well and it did not work out:

//ul[@aria-labelledby='p_n_feature_nine_browse-bin-title']/li

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that this checkbox is actually a link checkbox so what is needed to do is to click on the  element

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("English").click();
```

and that's would do the trick!